# Tailwind with Angular 13

Tags: angular, npm, web-applications, node-modules

when I run : ng add @ngneat/tailwind

I got this error:  An unhandled exception occurred: NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID  !!!!!!

VSCode.

Angular cli v: 13.1.2

npm v: 8.3.0

node v: 17.2.0

Win 10 64

Comment: Need more information. Please provide a stackblitz of the code or atleast the full stacktrace.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is an [open issue](https://github.com/ngneat/tailwind/issues/121) over at the people of `ngneat` and needs to be resolved by them as well.

I will share the [hotfix provided in the linked issue](https://github.com/ngneat/tailwind/issues/121#issuecomment-967727337). All credits to [kingjordan](https://github.com/ngneat/tailwind/issues/108#issuecomment-849616249):

```
Thanks to @kingjordan for his solution.

Install the dependencies:

npm install tailwindcss@latest @ngneat/tailwind@latest

Create a configuration file for Tailwind CSS at the root of your workspace:

npx tailwindcss init

Add purge configurations:

module.exports = {
  ...
  purge: {
    enabled: guessProductionMode(),
    content: [ "<path/to/project/**/*.{html, ts, jsx, etc}>" ],
  },
  ...
}

Import Tailwind CSS styles into the root styles file of your project.

@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use the steps of tailwind install for angular version [less then 11.2.0](https://dev.to/angular/setup-tailwindcss-in-angular-the-easy-way-1i5l#:%7E:text=in%203%20MINUTES!-,Installing%20TailwindCSS%20(Angular%20version%20%3E%3D%2011.2.0),-If%20your%20Angular)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[Link-only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info)"
and "[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/153968)"

Comment: Got it, have changed properly

Answer (score 0):

Install Tailwind CSS with Angular

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/angular

Tailwind is now officially supported by angular so no need to rely on community supported @ngneat/tailwind Package.